# É possível simplificar o comando Runnable numa função do Android?

Tags: java, android

Criei uma classe para facilitar a utilização de Dialogs, e gostaria de saber se é possível simplificar ainda mais.

Minha Classe está assim:

```
public class FVRDialog {
    private Activity act;
    private Context context;
    private AlertDialog dialog;

    public FVRDialog(Activity act) {
        this.act = act;
    }

    public boolean Confirm(int icon, String Title, String ConfirmText,
                       String OkBtn, String CancelBtn, final Runnable OkBtnPress, final Runnable CancelBtnPress) {

    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
    dialog.setTitle(Title);
    dialog.setMessage(ConfirmText);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    if (icon != 0) { dialog.setIcon(icon); }
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, OkBtn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                    OkBtnPress.run();
                }
            });
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, CancelBtn,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int buttonId) {
                    CancelBtnPress.run();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
    return true;
   }

    public void dismiss() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

E para executar eu estou fazendo assim:

```
final FVRDialogs fvrdialog = new FVRDialogs(this);
       fvrdialog.Confirm(@drawable/ic_pergunta, "Titulo", "Descrição", "Sim","Não",
           new Runnable() { public void run() { executarBtnSim(); } },
           new Runnable() { public void run() { executarBtnNao(); } });
```

Eu gostaria de simplificar sem precisar usar o runnable, deixar se possível, mais ou menos assim:

```
FVRDialogs fvrdialog = new FVRDialogs(this);
 fvrdialog.Confirm(@drawable/ic_pergunta, "Titulo", "Descrição", "Sim","Não", executarBtnSim(), executarBtnNao());
```

Ou se tiver algum outro jeito mais interessante de fazer istso, estou aberto a sugestões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Android Studio 3 dá suporte à algumas [funcionalidades do Java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html). Você pode habilitar isso adicionando as seguintes linhas no build.gradle:

```
android {
  ...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Desta forma você pode passar um lambda como parâmetro:

```
fvrdialog.confirm(@drawable/ic_pergunta, "Titulo", "Descrição", 
    "Sim","Não", () -> executarBtnSim(), () -> executarBtnNao());
```

Ou uma referência de método:

```
fvrdialog.confirm(@drawable/ic_pergunta, "Titulo", "Descrição", 
    "Sim","Não", this::executarBtnSim, this::executarBtnNao);
```

Comment: Eu diminuiria ainda mais a chamada à função. `this::executarBtnSim` eu acho mais digno de lambda do que `() -> this.executarBtnSim()`.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado bem observado. Adicionei na resposta

Comment: Obrigado amigos, funcionou bem para mim. Só tenho mais uma dúvida, na documentação mencionada ele explica algo sobre compatibilidade com `Jack`, o que seria isso? Será q posso ter problemas futuros de compatibilidade utilizando Java 8??

Comment: O que acontece é que na verdade o Android não dá suporte nativo ao Java 8 antes da versão 24. Eles usam uma ferramenta que traduz o seu código para uma versão compatível com o Java 7, um processo que eles chamam de  _desugaring_. A equipe do Google tinha desenvolvido o _Jack toolchain_ pra isso, mas eles resolveram abandoná-lo por uma solução melhor. Esta nova solução é suportada oficialmente pelo Google e você pode usá-la sem medo de problemas de compatibilidade.